# How to use more than one verb when starting a process?

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I am just printing a doc file using the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    Verb = "print",
    FileName = fileName //put the correct path here
};
p.Start();
```

What can I do so that I can keep the file open after printing or the other way around open the file first and then print it. Can I use more then one verb with a process?

Comment: Another useful application would be when using `Verb = "runas"` and a second one.

Comment: You are using the wrong hammer to hit that nail.  Add a reference to "Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library" in the COM tab.  Now you can do anything you like with it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Okay, that may work this time, but in general, it is possible? There is a `Verbs` property, but you can't set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Verbs are implemented as complete command lines: each verb corresponds to a full command-line, defined in the registry. Thus, each new verb would start an entirely different process, just happening to (usually) point to the same executable binary with different command-line args.

To control an application in more detail, you would have to resort to the program's automation technique, if there is one.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144148(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx):